# Change part of name with Javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few `select` elements on my page and i want to remove a part of the name.

Their name look something like this:

```
ctl02$fieldname
```

The part that i want to remove is: `ctl02$`. So that it leaves me with `fieldname` only.

That part that i want to remove always starts with `ctl` then a two digit number ending with a `$`.

I tried it with the following code, but that didn't do the trick:

```
$(".elements select").each(function() {
    this.setAttribute("name", this.getAttribute("name").replace(/ctl([0-9]+)\$$/, ""));
});
```

Anyone any idea how i can do this?

Here's a demo: http://tinkerbin.com/Klvx5qQF

Comment: Those look awfully similar to the names generated by asp.net web-forms. If you do use asp.net 4.0 or later, try using the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) to model the ID's on the server, with no need of client side mangling.

Comment: @SWeko Thanks for the advice. But unfortunately i'm using ASP.NET 3.5. So those are indeed generated names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just an error in the regex. I don't know why you doubled the `$`, a `$` at the end of a regex has a specific meaning that isn't what you want.

Here's the fixed version :

```
$(".elements select").each(function() {
    this.setAttribute("name", this.getAttribute("name").
       replace(/ctl[0-9]+\$/, ""));
});
```

You don't need to capture anything, that's why I also removed the parenthesis.

If you want to be sure to remove the ctl thing only when it's at the start of the name, you may change the regex to `/^ctl[0-9]+\$/`.

Answer (score 4):

I guess there is no need in regex here:

```
$(".elements select").attr("name", function(i, attr) {
    return attr.substring(attr.indexOf("$") + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
$(function() {
    $("select").each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr("name");

        $(this).attr("name", name.replace(/(ctl[0-9]+)/g, ""));

    });
});
```

see demo : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/yfV79/)